# How to parse a JSP and save to file in Spring MVC?

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I have some templates: JSP files with JSTL tags and some EL and want them to be parsed and saved to a file within the app folder, something like this:

**template.jsp**

```
<html>
...
<p>Hello ${ person.name }.</p>
...
```

**TemplatesController.java**

```
public void parse (Template template, Person person, Model model) {

  model.addAttribute (person);

  String jspFileAsString = template.parse (person, model);

  saveToFile (jspFileAsString);
}
```

And the result should be like **myapp/parsed-templates/template.html**

```
<html>
...
<p>Hello Michael.</p>
...
```

Should I create a `ViewResolver`? Thanks

Comment: it should be saved at runtime, right? you can simply create a xmlHttpRequest and send the html back to server.

Comment: that is a way, but they also should be saved by the service layer after performing different actions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSP rendering is usually out of the scope of a `Spring MVC` request handling. I think it will be easier if you create a custom [Filter](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html) and a mock [HttpServletResponse](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html):

Instead of the original response, `Spring MVC` will write on this mock response. Then, you must get the result as String and write to a file and finally write to the original response too. Remember that you must include all headers, status code, etc.

Comment: Please provide examples, references, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Just save the parameters, and the call the controller method again. It will be the same and its kinda what its for.

Saving the generated html of a parsed jsp page seems like a bad idea.

Comment: Saving the parsed file is a requirement specified by the client.